# In python, how can I check if a filename ends in '.html' or '_files'?

Tags: python, html

In python, how can I check if a filename ends in '.html' or '_files'?

Comment: Do you mean if a *filename* ends in `.html` or `_files`?

Comment: Yes that's what i meant, sorry don't speak english very well

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably want to know if a file *name* ends in these strings, not the file istelf:

```
if file_name.endswith((".html", "_files")):
    # whatever
```

To test whether a file ends in one of these strings, you can do this:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    f.seek(-6, 2)           # only read the last 6 characters of the file
    if f.read().endswith((".html", "_files")):
        # whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little bit more comprehensive.

```
dirname = os.getcwd()
file_extension_type = ('.html', '_files') # , '.exe', 'jpg', '...')
 
# iterating over all files
for file in os.listdir(dirname):
    if file.endswith(file_extension_type):
        print("Found a file {}".format(file))  # printing file name of desired extension
    else:
        continue
```